# How to create "retry" connection to connect to share network?

Tags: powershell, share

I want to connect to share folder. I want to do retry connection to share folder that I want if the connection still not connected after that I do my next process.

I tried this code. I can connect to the server. But If the connection has problem, It just waiting about 5 second, then return that the network is not found.

```bsh
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("P:", "\\192.168.1.2\Temp\BP", $False, "008", "25")

if(Test-Path -Path "P:"){
  Write-Host "Connected"
}
else
{
  Write-Host "Try Again"
  $net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
  $net.MapNetworkDrive("P:", "\\$Get_IP\Temp\BP", $False, "$008", "$25")
}

$Next = "Do Next Process"
```

My expectation, I can have retry connection first. Until it connected, then do next process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize a loop to do so, in that example `do...until`:

```bsh
$n = 0
do {
  $net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
  $net.MapNetworkDrive("P:", "\\192.168.1.2\Temp\BP", $False, "008", "25")
  $n++
  Write-Host "Attempt no $n"
} until ((Test-Path -Path "P:") -or ($n -ge 30))

# Information about success/failure
if (Test-Path -Path "P:") {
  Write-Host "Connected successfully after $n attempts"
} else {
  Write-Host "Connection failed"
}
```

To avoid infinite loop, I added the counter `$n` and specified to end loop after 30 attempts. Feel free to edit that number to your needs.

[Related article if you want to learn more about loops](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-loops-for-foreach-while-do-until-continue-break/).

---

**EDIT**: as per comments + chat discussion, here the code which will attempt to connect indefinitely and not return any info in case of failure

*I personally don't recommend that solution because of infinite loop and no information about the failure which might be useful for debugging.*

```bsh
$n = 0
do {
  $n++
  $net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
  $net.MapNetworkDrive("P:", "\\192.168.1.2\Temp\BP", $False, "008", "25")
  Write-Host "Attempt no $n"
} until (Test-Path -Path "P:")

Write-Host "Connected successfully after $n attempts"
```

Similar solution can be rewritten as function (using `While` loop this time as I don't want reconnection to happen if the share is already connected):

```bsh
function Check-ConnectionToServer {
$n = 0
while (-not (Test-Path -Path "P:")) {
  $n++
  $net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
  $net.MapNetworkDrive("P:", "\\192.168.1.2\Temp\BP", $False, "008", "25")
  Write-Host "Attempt no $n"
}
Write-Host "Connected successfully after $n attempts"
return $true
}
```

and then use it anytime you want to make sure that the connection is active.

```bsh
# Previous cmdlets
Check-ConnectionToServer
# Next cmdlets
```

Comment: But I can not see how many times it try to connect to the server. And I chnge the end loop from `30` to `2` , but  it do the same things.

Comment: I added some `Write-Host` cmdlets to that - is that what you want to see?

Comment: I don't want to return that connection failed. I want to always try to check the connection without return connection failed until connection is connected, then do the next process

Comment: Then just remove that part in your code. I don't want to remove it from my answer as it gives an additional information for debugging. You are free to edit the code I provided before you push your script to production, but I try to keep my answer valuable for possible future readers too.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer still not what I expect for.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you expect in your question? I'm trying to better understand.

Comment: I want to check the connection continually without return that connection fail. I have to check everytime until it connected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196035/discussion-between-robdy-and-job).

Comment: Wow.. Great to see it. Thank you for your answer. it helps me.